# KnockoutJS Add, Edit, Delete

Tags: knockout.js, addition, edit

The following is a sample structure of the object:

```
[{
    MasterType: "mtype1",
    Types: [{
        TypeStage: "st1",
        TypeDate: "12/02/2001",
        SubTypes: [{
            SubTypeData: "st1"
        }, {
            AnotherData: "ad1"
        }]
    }, {
        TypeStage: "st3",
        TypeDate: "15/02/2001",
        SubTypes: [{
            SubTypeData: "st3"
        }, {
            AnotherData: "ad3"
        }]
    }]
},

{
    MasterType: "mtype2",
    Types: [{
        TypeStage: "st2",
        TypeDate: "12/04/2001",
        SubTypes: [{
            SubTypeData: "st2"
        }, {
            AnotherData: "ad2"
        }]
    }]
}];
```

NOTE: On page-load, the object is empty.

I need to display a table of MasterType with edit/delete for each row.
I also, need an ‘Add’ button, which then HIDES the table and shows the input fields to enter the values for the new MasterType.
Once the new MasterType is saved, I need to hide the input fields and display the table again.

Please help

I have done the following:

```
                <table>
                    <tbody  data-bind="foreach: MasterTypes">
                        <tr><td data-bind='text: MasterType'></td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div >
                    <table>
                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: MasterTypes">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <input data-bind="value: MasterType,valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
                                    <div><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeMasterType'>Delete</a></div>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <table>
                                        <tbody data-bind="foreach: Types">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><input data-bind='value: TypeStage' /></td>
                                                <td><input data-bind='value: TypeDate' /></td>
                                                <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeType'>Delete</a></td>
                                                <td>
                                                <table>
                                                    <tbody data-bind="foreach: SubTypes">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td><input data-bind='value: Discharge' /></td>
                                                            <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeSubType'>Delete</a></td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                                <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addSubType'>Add New Sub type</a>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
                                    <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addType'>Add new Type</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <p>
                    <button data-bind='click: addMasterType'>Add New MasterType</button>
                    <button data-bind='click: save, enable: MasterTypes().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>
                </p>

                <textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'> </textarea>
                <script type="text/javascript">

                    var MasterTypesModel = function (mastertypes) {
                        var self = this;
                        self.tableVisible = ko.observable(true);
                        self.MasterTypes = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(mastertypes, function (mastertype) {
                           return { MasterType: mastertype.MasterType, Types: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(mastertype.Types, function (type) {
                               return { TypeStage: type.TypeStage, TypeDate: type.TypeDate, SubTypes: ko.observableArray(type.SubTypes) };
                           }))
                           };
                        }));

                        self.addMasterType = function () {
                          // self.tableVisible(false);
                           self.MasterTypes.push({
                               MasterType: "",
                               Types: ko.observableArray(
                                        [{ TypeStage: "", TypeDate: "", SubTypes: ko.observableArray()}]
                                    )
                           });
                        };

                        self.removeMasterType = function (mastertype) {
                           self.MasterTypes.remove(mastertype);
                        };

                        self.addType = function (mastertype) {
                           mastertype.Types.push({
                               TypeStage: "",
                               TypeDate: "",
                               SubTypes: ko.observableArray()
                           });
                        };

                        self.removeType = function (type) {
                           $.each(self.MasterTypes(), function () {
                               this.Types.remove(type)
                           })
                        };

                        self.addSubType = function (type) {
                           type.SubTypes.push({
                               Discharge: ""
                           });
                        };

                        self.removeSubType = function (subtype) {
                           $.each(self.MasterTypes(), function () {
                               $.each(this.Types(), function () {
                                   this.SubTypes.remove(subtype)
                               })
                           })
                        };

                        self.save = function () {
                           self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.MasterTypes), null, 2));
                           $.ajax({
                               url: "/MyController/UpdateMasterType",
                               contentType: 'application/json',
                               type: 'POST',
                               data: ko.toJSON(self.MasterTypes),
                               success: function (data) {
                                   self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
                                   alert('That is it!');
                               }
                           });
                        };

                        self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
                    };                   

                    ko.applyBindings(new MasterTypesModel());

                </script>
```

Comment: What have you done yet ?

Comment: Please see the edited post to see what I have got yet. I was unable to add it as a comment as it was more than the allowed number of characters.

Comment: Thanks for your time everyone... I have found the answer.... Please find the original post edited which has got the answer at the end.

Comment: Please consider deleting this question. It is unlikely to be of use to anyone else, as it doesn't apply to a general problem.

Answer (score 0):

The OP wrote:

> Thanks everyone.... I have found the answer:
>
> ```
>               <table data-bind="visible:tableVisible">      
>                     <tr><td> <button data-bind='click: addMasterType'>Add New MasterType</button></td></tr>
>                         <!-- ko foreach: MasterTypes -->
>                         <tr>
>                             <td data-bind='text: MasterType'></td>
>                             <td><button data-bind='click: $root.editMasterType'>Edit</button></td>                                
>                         </tr>
>                         <!-- /ko -->    
>                 </table>
>
>                 <div >
>                     <table>
>                         <tbody data-bind="with: SelectedMasterType">
>                             <tr>
>                                 <td>
>                                     <input data-bind="value: MasterType,valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />                                        
>                                 </td>
>                                 <td>
>                                     <table>
>                                         <tbody data-bind="foreach: Types">
>                                             <tr>
>                                                 <td><input data-bind='value: TypeStage' /></td>
>                                                 <td><input data-bind='value: TypeDate' /></td>
>                                                 <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeType'>Delete</a></td>
>                                                 <td>
>                                                 <table>
>                                                     <tbody data-bind="foreach: SubTypes">
>                                                         <tr>
>                                                             <td><input data-bind='value: Discharge' /></td>
>                                                             <td><a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removeSubType'>Delete</a></td>
>                                                         </tr>
>                                                     </tbody>
>                                                 </table>
>                                                 <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addSubType'>Add New Sub type</a>
>                                             </tr>
>                                         </tbody>
>                                     </table>
>                                     <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.addType'>Add new Type</a>
>                                 </td>
>                             </tr>
>                         </tbody>
>                     </table>
>                 </div>
>
>                 <p>
>                     <button data-bind='click: addMasterType'>Add New MasterType</button>
>                     <button data-bind='click: save, enable: MasterTypes().length > 0'>Save to JSON</button>
>                 </p>
>
>                 <textarea data-bind='value: lastSavedJson' rows='5' cols='60' disabled='disabled'> </textarea>
>                 <script type="text/javascript">
>
>                    var MasterTypesModel = function (mastertypes) {
>                        var self = this;
>                        self.SelectedMasterType = ko.observable(null);
>                        self.tableVisible = ko.observable(true);
>                        self.MasterTypes = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(mastertypes, function (mastertype) {
>                            return { MasterType: ko.observable(mastertype.MasterType), Types: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(mastertype.Types, function (type) {
>                                return { TypeStage: type.TypeStage, TypeDate: type.TypeDate, SubTypes: ko.observableArray(type.SubTypes) };
>                            }))
>                            };
>                        }));
>
>                        self.addMasterType = function () {
>                            self.tableVisible(false);
>                            self.MasterTypes.push({
>                                MasterType: ko.observable(""),
>                                Types: ko.observableArray(
>                                         [{ TypeStage: "", TypeDate: "", SubTypes: ko.observableArray()}]
>                                     )
>                            });
>                            self.SelectedMasterType(self.MasterTypes()[self.MasterTypes().length - 1]);
>                        };
>
>                        self.editMasterType = function (masteryype) {
>                            self.tableVisible(false);
>                            self.SelectedMasterType(masteryype);
>                        };
>
>                        self.removeMasterType = function (mastertype) {
>                            self.MasterTypes.remove(mastertype);
>                        };
>
>                        self.addType = function (mastertype) {
>                            mastertype.Types.push({
>                                TypeStage: "",
>                                TypeDate: "",
>                                SubTypes: ko.observableArray()
>                            });
>                        };
>
>                        self.removeType = function (type) {
>                            $.each(self.MasterTypes(), function () {
>                                this.Types.remove(type)
>                            })
>                        };
>
>                        self.addSubType = function (type) {
>                            type.SubTypes.push({
>                                Discharge: ""
>                            });
>                        };
>
>                        self.removeSubType = function (subtype) {
>                            $.each(self.MasterTypes(), function () {
>                                $.each(this.Types(), function () {
>                                    this.SubTypes.remove(subtype)
>                                })
>                            })
>                        };
>
>                        self.save = function () {
>                          self.lastSavedJson(JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.MasterTypes), null, 2));
>                            $.ajax({
>                                url: "/MyController/UpdateMasterType",
>                                contentType: 'application/json',
>                                type: 'POST',
>                                data: ko.toJSON(self.MasterTypes),
>                                success: function (data) {
>                                    self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
>                                    self.SelectedMasterType(null);
>                                    self.tableVisible(true);
>                                    alert('That is it!');
>                                }
>                            });
>                        };
>
>                        self.lastSavedJson = ko.observable("")
>                    };
>
>                    ko.applyBindings(new MasterTypesModel());
>
>                 </script>
> ```

Comment: ([Question answered in an edit and converted to a community wiki](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que).)